# TeXstudio 2.6.2 internal pdf previewer

Tags: texstudio

How to disable continuous view in the internal previever? I need it to preview beamer presentations properly.

I have TeXstudio 2.6.2 installed on Lubuntu 13.04

Comment: have you tried to setup in _Options->configurate TexStudio->Preview_ ?

Comment: Of course I have. There is no possibility even in advanced options.

Comment: I think, I don't understand your problem properly.

Comment: This is currently only configurable if the interal viewer is windowed (not embedded in the main window). In the viewer window, uncheck `View -> Continuous`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Copied from my comment above:

This is currently only configurable if the interal viewer is windowed (not embedded in the main window). In the viewer window, uncheck `View -> Continuous`.