# TeXstudio pre-viewing options

Tags: texstudio, preview

In TeXstudio, is it possible to set the internal previewer to a single-page view? Is it possible to do so in a combination with the option "Fit to Text Width"?

**Edit:** The answer at [TeXstudio 2.6.2 internal pdf previewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161526/texstudio-2-6-2-internal-pdf-previewer) did help, but not quite, to answer my questions -- see my answer below for details.

Comment: In a nutshell: No.

Comment: Do you mean no even to the first question: is it possible to set the internal previewer to a single-page view?

Comment: By 'internal previewer', do you mean the embedded PDF viewer? And does 'Fit to Text Window' refer to the zoom option 'Fit to Window' ?

Comment: @Troy : The viewer may be a PDF one or dvipng or any other TeXstudio may have, but I would like it to be internal, rather than an external one. As for "Fit to Text Window", I meant "Fit to Text Width" -- sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification. One more thing, 'single-page view' you're referring to, is as opposed to 'continuous scrolling'?

Comment: @Troy : Yes,  'single-page view' as opposed to 'continuous scrolling'.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I mean that as far I can see, the internal viewer have no option to show single-page views.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161526/117534. It was a 'No' from the author of TeXstudio three years ago, doesn't seem to be possible today as well.

Comment: @Troy : That answer by Tim Hoffmann was: "This is currently only configurable if the interal viewer is windowed (not embedded in the main window). In the viewer window, uncheck View -> Continuous" and it apparently pertained only to TeXstudio 2.6.2. In my version, 2.12.6, choosing the viewer windowed does not seem to have any effect and leaves it embedded, and no unchecking of continuous view seems possible. I wonder why that must be so; a single-page view is so basic.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to my question, I wrote:

> That answer by Tim Hoffmann [at [TeXstudio 2.6.2 internal pdf previewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161526/texstudio-2-6-2-internal-pdf-previewer) ] was: "This is currently only configurable
>   if the interal viewer is windowed (not embedded in the main window).
>   In the viewer window, uncheck View -> Continuous" and it apparently
>   pertained only to TeXstudio 2.6.2. In my version, 2.12.6, choosing the
>   viewer windowed does not seem to have any effect and leaves it
>   embedded

Indeed, choosing windowed viewer in the options (the way described in the manual) does nothing: 
[image]

However, I have just happened to find a way to get the viewer windowed, by clicking on this icon in the viewer:

[image]

Then one can indeed uncheck View -> Continuous. However, then the single-page view is not working well with "Fit to Text Width" -- as compared with Sumatra PDF's "Fit Content" option, say.